# I am trying to hide text in a ASPX page that is tied to a textbox

Tags: c#, asp.net, jquery

So there is a a table and a text box in one of the cells

```
<td>
    <asp:TextBox ID="tbSomeTextBox" Columns="5" runat="server"> % 
</td>
```

This textbox gets shown if a certain selection is made in a drop down.  The problem is that I would like the "%" character to also be hidden or shown with the textbox.

I have tried putting the whole textbox control inside a DIVand in my JQuery hiding the DIV at the same time I hid the textbox.

```
<td>
    <div id="divSomeDIV"><asp:TextBox ID="tbSomeTextBox" Columns="5" runat="server"> % </div
</td>
```

But I get an error in my java script that id="divSomeDIV" doesn't exist in the current context.

```
$("#<%=divSomeDiv.ClientID%>").hide();
```

Wrapping that single character in a asp:Label seems like overkill.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

divSomeDiv is running client-side (i.e. no "runat=server"), so there's no need for

```
$("#<%=divSomeDiv.ClientID%>").hide();
```

Just do

```
$("#divSomeDiv").hide();
```

Comment: Because I was trying to use the server side ID, was that the cause of the "does not exist in the current context" error?

Comment: @pghtech: Indeed. The server did not find the variable on its side, so it's threw the error. If you look at your generated web page code, <%=tbSomeTextBox.ClientId%>'s real name is something like contentPlaceHolder1_tbSomeTextBox. No need for the <%%> tags on the client.

Answer (score 0):

create an asp.net label, set the label value to be %, and make them both visible or both not visible at the same time... ?

Answer (score 0):

If you were getting "does not exist" in your Javascript it's probably because your Javascript is running before the div is created in the dom. In other words, this is incorrect.

```
<script>$("#divSomeDiv").hide()</script>
<div id="divSomeDiv">...</div>
```

You can either put the Javascript after the div

```
<div id="divSomeDiv">...</div>
<script>$("#divSomeDiv").hide()</script>
```

Or you can make your Javascript run after the DOM has loaded.

```
<script>
  $(function() {
    $("#divSomeDiv").hide()
  });
</script>
<div id="divSomeDiv">...</div>
```